# executing csv copy command from remote machine with jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

How to create stdin object to pass as a parameter to  copy command for csv upload into db table and execute with jdbc api

Example that i tried

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/517037/Desktop/new.csv")));

copy temp123 from "+in.read()+" using delimiters '|'
```

But here i am getting error.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "48"
  Position: 19

can any one help me out in this

Comment: Do you want to store a CSV file as column data in DB table?

Comment: yes i want to upload csv file to table columns using jdbc

Comment: and my db server is in remote machine

Comment: It doesn't matter where the DB is in. But please make sure the user has privileges to edit or store.

Comment: You are getting such error because `in.read()` when added to string const is converted to string and probably you get some garbage here (for example class and method name with some address).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invoking `copy` command with full file name like:

```
copy temp123 from 'C:/Documents and Settings/517037/Desktop/new.csv' using delimiters '|'
```

If it do not work, then you can try code:

```
copy temp123 from stdin using delimiters '|'
```

and then invoke your Java program with redirecting of stdin:

```
c:\tmp>java my_import < "C:\Documents and Settings\517037\Desktop\new.csv"
```

Comment: For `copy` command with file this file must be "visible" to server. If you can then simply copy it to temp directory visible to server. If not then try my edited answer with stdin redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link of how to store BLOB or CLOB(Binary large objects). It contains comprehensive list of examples for storing those types.Please make sure to check the specific database documentation in addition to that.

[Storing CLOB or BLOB to DB](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/StoreCLOBsdataintodatabase.htm)